# Issue with converting a filesystem path to a const BYTE*

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, c++17, registry

What I'm trying to achieve is getting my program executed on Windows startup using the Registry. When I try to put the file location, the compiler complains it cannot convert from `filesystem::path` to `const BYTE*`. I have no idea how to fix this, since I'm a beginner when it comes to C++. I have provided the code below:

```cpp
HKEY newValue;
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", &newValue);
RegSetValueEx(newValue, "myprogram", 0, REG_SZ, fs::temp_directory_path().append(filename), sizeof("tes3t")); // This line is the issue. fs::temp_directory_path().append(filename)
RegCloseKey(newValue);
return 0;
```

> EXCEPTION: No suitable conversion function from "std:filesystem::path" to "const BYTE *" exists

Comment: Do yourself a favor and store the desired value into an intermediate variable.  Then you will easily separate the path manipulation from the registry access function calls.

Comment: Im sorry but like i stated before that im quite new to c++ and i have no idea what you meant by that, im more of a visual person. Could you please provide me an example?

Comment: He means you're packing too much stuff into too small a space. If you perform each step on its own, storing results in to temporary variables, you can more easily see exactly where the problem is. Once an error is isolated, fixing the error is usually easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`RegSetValueExA()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa), the function does not  accept a `std::filesystem::path` object.  That is what the error message is complaining about.

```c
LSTATUS RegSetValueExA(
  HKEY       hKey,
  LPCSTR     lpValueName,
  DWORD      Reserved,
  DWORD      dwType,
  const BYTE *lpData, // <-- here
  DWORD      cbData
);
```

The 5th parameter takes a `const BYTE*` pointer to a **null-terminated C-style string**. The 6th parameter takes the number of characters in the string, including the null terminator:

> `lpData`
>
> The data to be stored.
>
> **For string-based types, such as REG_SZ, the string must be null-terminated**. With the REG_MULTI_SZ data type, the string must be terminated with two null characters.
>
> Note  *lpData* indicating a null value is valid, however, if this is the case, *cbData* must be set to '0'.
>
> `cbData`
>
> The size of the information pointed to by the *lpData* parameter, in bytes. **If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, *cbData* must include the size of the terminating null character or characters**.

`std::filesystem::path` does not have an *implicit* conversion to `const BYTE*`, hence the compiler error.  You need to *explicitly* convert the `path` to a `std::string` or `std::wstring` first (prefer the latter, since the Registry stores strings as Unicode internally), before you can then save that string value to the Registry, eg:

```cpp
// using std::string...

HKEY newValue;

// don't use RegOpenKey()! It is provided only for backwards compatibility with 16bit apps...
if (RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &newValue) == 0)
{
    // this may lose data for non-ASCII characters!
    std::string s = fs::temp_directory_path().append(filename).string();

    // this will convert the ANSI string to Unicode for you...
    RegSetValueExA(newValue, "myprogram", 0, REG_SZ, reinterpret_cast<LPCBYTE>(s.c_str()), s.size()+1);

    RegCloseKey(newValue);
}

return 0;
```

```cpp
// using std::wstring...

HKEY newValue;

// don't use RegOpenKey()! It is provided only for backwards compatibility with 16bit apps...
if (RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &newValue) == 0)
{
    // no data loss here!
    std::wstring s = fs::temp_directory_path().append(filename).wstring();

    // no ANSI->Unicode conversion is performed here...
    RegSetValueExW(newValue, L"myprogram", 0, REG_SZ, reinterpret_cast<LPCBYTE>(s.c_str()), (s.size()+1) * sizeof(WCHAR));

    RegCloseKey(newValue);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for helping me with this... I kinda feel bad that i dont understand the code... But ill learn.. Eventaually. Im accepting this as the answer because you provided me with 2 solutions and you gave information about why it wasnt working. This is very oftopic and i just want to ask is it normal to not understand the code? Cause it makes me feel stupid aha, thanks again.

EDIT: the line i dont understand "reinterpret_cast<LPCBYTE>"

Comment: It's semi-normal, but it's dangerous. If you don't understand the code, there's no way you can fix it when it breaks. You need to frame problems in a manner that you can understand, and usually this is done [by making smaller problems](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) and attacking the smaller problems one at a time..

Comment: @JakeNiledon `LPCBYTE` is just an alias for `const BYTE*`. The [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) is because `std::(w)string::c_str()` returns a `const char*`/`const wchar_t*`, which must be type-casted from one type to another.

Answer (score 2):

The WinAPI functions do not take arguments of `std::filesystem::path` type so you need to convert it to a `const BYTE*` somehow.

This is one example:

```
std::string fullpath = (fs::temp_directory_path() / filename).string();

RegSetValueEx(
    newValue,
    "myprogram",
    0,
    REG_SZ,
    reinterpret_cast<LPCBYTE>(fullpath.c_str()), // returns a "const char*" then cast
    fullpath.size() + 1  // + 1 for null terminator
);
```